# Why some kernel modules are marked (F)

Tags: module, linux-kernel

Some of the modules listed in */proc/modules* are marked (F) - I think means forcefully loaded.
I am sure they were not. If I unload and the reload the module the (F) disappears.

For example:

```
squashfs 47871 1 - Live 0xffffffffa0100000 (F)
ast 56335 1 - Live 0xffffffffa00c4000 (F)
ttm 79926 1 ast, Live 0xffffffffa00e5000 (F)
drm_kms_helper 50129 1 ast, Live 0xffffffffa00d7000 (F)
drm 272304 3 ast,ttm,drm_kms_helper, Live 0xffffffffa0080000 (F)
i2c_algo_bit 13250 1 ast, Live 0xffffffffa0053000 (F)
i2c_core 38513 6 i2c_dev,i2c_i801,ast,drm_kms_helper,drm,i2c_algo_bit, \
        Live 0xffffffffa0075000 (F)
usb_storage 56610 0 - Live 0xffffffffa005d000 (F)
mpt2sas 189642 16 - Live 0xffffffffa0023000 (F)
scsi_transport_sas 39231 1 mpt2sas, Live 0xffffffffa0012000 (F)
```

Comment: Maybe question is not clear enough. Could anyone suggest where to look to find the cause of the (F). I am sure the modules were not forcefully loaded and they were built together with the kernel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [source](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/module.c), Luke!

```c
static size_t module_flags_taint(struct module *mod, char *buf)
{
    size_t l = 0;

    if (mod->taints & (1 << TAINT_PROPRIETARY_MODULE))
        buf[l++] = 'P';
    if (mod->taints & (1 << TAINT_OOT_MODULE))
        buf[l++] = 'O';
    if (mod->taints & (1 << TAINT_FORCED_MODULE))
        buf[l++] = 'F';
    if (mod->taints & (1 << TAINT_CRAP))
        buf[l++] = 'C';
    if (mod->taints & (1 << TAINT_UNSIGNED_MODULE))
        buf[l++] = 'E';
    /*
     * TAINT_FORCED_RMMOD: could be added.
     * TAINT_CPU_OUT_OF_SPEC, TAINT_MACHINE_CHECK, TAINT_BAD_PAGE don't
     * apply to modules.
     */
    return l;
}
```

The modules definitely were forced.
(This can also happen when the kernel was compiled with version information, but the modules were not.)